# css - How to put Highcharts containers in rows of 2?

Tags: css, highcharts

I am not sure how to do this; never did CSS before, and the experiments are pretty much unsuccessful.

I have various charts drawn with Highcharts, into divs; I would like to have them all in 2 rows, since now they are displayed in a single row.

I tried to add a new div, and include the 2 divs inside this other main div, and use float; in this case the charts are side by side, but I can't add some space between them

This is what I have so far; the chart size is 530 by 200, so 2 side by side should take 1060px, I have set it to have 1200px for the main div, so there should be plenty of space. What am i doing wrong here?

```
<style>
        #main {
            width: 1200px ;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        #chart_1 {
            width 530px;
            min-height: 200px;
            float:left;
        }
        #chart_2 {
            width 530px;
            min-height: 200px;
            float:left;
        }
        .clear:after {
            clear: both;
            display: table;
            content: "";
        }       
</style>

<div id="main" class="clear">
        <div id="chart_1""></div> 
        <div id="chart_2""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle ? maybe you can try with css percentage.

Comment: Found a mistake; now the charts are side by side, but can't add space between them. Made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/newbiez/AeFp3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HS42E/ with some padding ?

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AeFp3/2/).
You missed the `:` after `width` for both elements in `style`.
You have an additional `"` for both elements after `id`

Comment: Thanks Sup4; that's it! @Rohit: thanks for the correction on the typos; btw it was working also without correction...no idea how and why

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
        #main {
            width: 1200px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        #chart_1 {
            width: 530px; /*<-- missing colon tag here */
            min-height: 200px;
            float:left;
        }
        #chart_2 {
            width: 530px; /*<-- missing colon tag here */
            min-height: 200px;
            float:left;
        }
        .clear:after {
            clear: both;
            display: table;
            content: "";
        }       
</style>

<div id="main" class="clear">
        <div id="chart_1"></div> <!-- Additional quote after id -->
        <div id="chart_2"></div> <!-- Additional quote after id -->
</div>
```

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/AeFp3/2/)